# Is there a way to see the top answers by upvotes for a given tag?

Tags: support, tags, search

The votes tab shows "Questions with the most votes". I would like to be able to see answers with the most votes. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

There's already a way to do this using the site search.

Searching `[tag] is:a` will net you answers from questions in that specific tag. The search screen then has a sort option of vote. Selecting this sort option gives you answers in that tag, sorted from most to least votes.

If you're already on a tag's question list, you can just add `is:a`, or `is:answer` if you prefer, to the search box, as the tag will already be populated there.